# Change the order of CSS transition

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

Let's assume that I have a code:

```js
$('.box').click(function(){
  $('.box').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  transition: left 1s, transform 1s 2s;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.box.active {
  left: 100px;
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box"></div>
```

Now, due to the transition delay in the transform property, after clicking the div, the div will first move towards right and then its size will increase.

When we click the div again, it will first move towards left and then its size will decrease.

I want to change the order of the transition such that when we click the div the second time, it first decreases its size and then moves towards left. How can I do that?

Comment: this will not work if i add delay on the left then the only thing that will happen the net animation will start after some time

Comment: and remove it from transform of course .. you invert ...

Comment: This will not work as we need to change those values that you are saying when we click the div the second time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a different transition on the active class where you add a delay to the left property

```js
$('.box').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
.box {
  position:relative;
  margin:100px;
  background:red;
  Height: 50px;
  Width: 50px;
  transition: 1s left, 1s transform 2s;
  left:0;
}

.box.active {
  left: 100px;
  transform: scale(2);
  transition: 1s left 2s, 1s transform;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add the delay to the left when your class insn't active instead and add the opposite configuration to when the class is active:

```js
$('.box').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
.box {
  position:relative;
  margin:100px;
  background:red;
  Height: 50px;
  Width: 50px;
  transition: 1s left 2s, 1s transform;
  left:0;
}

.box.active {
  left: 100px;
  transform: scale(2);
  transition: 1s left, 1s transform  2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```